# Why is my bar tape wearing out quicker on one side?

Tags: road-bike, handlebar-tape

My bar tape has been wearing out on the left where my palm meets the bar with I ride on the hoods, but not on the right. I've noticed the same thing on the gloves I usually wear.

Is this cause by how I'm cycling or is it more to do with bike fit? I can't think of why there would be an imbalance if it was to do with fit.

Comment: Do you have left or right hand traffic? Here in right hand traffic I have to signal much more often with my left hand. In which order do you go down to the drops? I haven’t observed this personally yet, my bar tape usually wears down from crashes or because I lean the bike against walls.

Comment: Are you left- or right-handed, there may also be an imbalance in your grip, like holding the bar tighter with you left hand

Comment: Have you ever checked your arms to see if they are the same length?  Serious suggestion - none of us are perfectly symmetrical.  Could even be a spinal curve or a hip imbalance, which makes you habitually lean to the left, unconsciously.

Comment: Also look at storage. That sounds a little high on the bar tape to be from habitual scuffing against a wall, but it's possible depending on how you hold the bars.  This could also lead to grit, which would abrade your gloves

Comment: @Michael, left hand traffic here, not sure if I would signal either side more than the other though. I probably lead with the right into drops and because the wear is on the top of the bar, I don't think its from walls.

Comment: @Carel Right-handed here, could be a grip imbalance.

Comment: @Criggie I've never measured, but entirely possible. You could be on to something with a spinal or hip imbalance too.

Comment: @ChrisH Just due to the fact that the wear is on the top of the bars, I think this might be unlikely.

Comment: Oh, one more: Are you riding with panniers on one side only? Or other asymmetrical weight distribution? It would essentially make you lean to one side all the time, although the effect is tiny.

Comment: You're probably right, but my MTB hangs up and the wheel rests on the bars of my road bike if I don't secure it, so storage can affect the tops in edge cases

Comment: I don't know about the glove, but if wind of the tape is the same side to side instead of mirror image, that could explain the tape wear even if everything you were doing with your body was symmetrical. One side's tape would be getting twisted in the tightening direction, and the other in the loosening.

Comment: Also possible that handlebars are ever-so-slightly misaligned relative to the front wheel which could result in a small difference in distribution of weight to the bars